# Connecting ONLY on server side on facebook

Tags: php, authentication, facebook-graph-api

There is any way to login on Facebook ( Server side with FAcebook PHP API ), without prompting the login mask ?
The problem is that i must create an automatic alerting on a Facebook group, and thus the my site should login on Facebook and write the new status, without prompting anything to the user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Authentication is there for what it was originally meant for..!! You can include those api within your application with some config files which stores your facebook username, password. But then you should have some authetication for your application.. So be clear how you are going to update status. ? In turn u can also create a RSS feed for your website and then link them to update to facebook

Comment: Fist of all thanks for the Answer! 
Now i will try to clear my problem:
I have a web-based software that manage all courses,prof,students of an Italian conservatorium. The goal is that when the prof submit the exam results or any other communication, the software write a new status on the Official Facebook group.
So the **theorical** passages are:
User submit a communication -> The site login via Facebook API -> The site write a status, always via API -> OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, For the first time the user is using your app, the user must accept your app. In that case facebook pops up a dialog for the user to allow your app. This i think will always happen at least once.

What you can do then, is to request for offline permission from the user. You can then store the token generated by facebook. With this token you can perform actions on the user's behalf without the user login in to facebook.

That is what i think.

Comment: mmmh Interesting!, but this token have an expire date ?

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your flow is whenever u submit a new thing into your site, it should be automatically gets updated into your facebook profile.

If that the case, have a look at [ping.fm](http://ping.fm) and [hellotxt](http://hellotxt.com) and they are providing API for that.. From that, you can update many social networking sites at once.

Just register with any of these services and the API to update the status at the end of the script where u add/upload things or stuffs..